# Add class to a html element dynamically

Tags: angularjs

In the below code i want to add class to those row in which notes are more than 20.is there any way to add class according to my reqirement

```
<td> {{ participant.ParticipationRole }} </td>
                            <td> {{ participant.AvailableDate | date: "dd-MMM-yyyy" }} </td>
                            <td> {{ participant.Notes | limitTo: 20 }} {{participant.Notes.length < 20 ? '' : '...'}}</td>
```

Comment: ngClass: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class :

```
<td ng-class="{ 'myClass': participant.Notes.length < 20 }"> Data </td>
```